# TransferFrom ERC20 token to burn address from another Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, erc-20, transferfrom

I am working on a migration contract and the flow is as follows:

Contract function calculates balance of XXX coin
-> Contract sends amount XXX of OLD token to burn address
-> Contract sends xxx of new token to msg.sender

I am having issues with the middle part and the `transferFrom()` call is giving me the below error:

> transact to DeadTokenMigration.migrate errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

I realize this is quite a common error, but I cannot figure out which account is actually at fault here

Here is the code of the function:

```
 function migrate() public virtual{

// gets Dead CoinBalance for a user.
XXXBalance = DeadToken(CoinToBeConverted).balanceOf(_msgSender());

//For TRansparency, old coins are sent to the Burn Address
require(XXXXBalance > 0, "Balance too small to migrate!");
DeadToken(CoinToBeConverted).transferFrom(_msgSender(), address(0), XXXXBalance);

// Transfer from RCVR Migration contract to msg.sender
XXXX(XXXXAddress).transfer(_msgSender(),XXXXBalance);
```

}
}

The First and last functions work so getting the balance and transferring the new tokens across

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `transferFrom()`, you first need to call `approve()`. You can read about it [here](https://medium.com/ethex-market/erc20-approve-allow-explained-88d6de921ce9), but basically you need to give the contract permission to send the tokens on your behalf.

The `approve()` must be performed in a different transaction before this one.

Comment: Thank you so much, ive just tried now and thats worked. I really appreciate the time youve taken to help me out!